# Fibre patching from one cabinet to another via an intermediary

Tags: patch-panel

I want to patch OM4 from cabinet 1 to cabinet 3 but there isn’t a patch panel directly from 1 to 3. However, there is patch panels from 1 to 2 and 2 to 3. The patch panels are LC connectors and the fibre is OM4.

Can I patch from cabinet 1 to 2, then from 2 to 3 or is that considered bad practice?

Comment: It all depends on your power budget.  Can you afford the loss caused by the extra patches?

Comment: Yes, but remember that each connection attenuates the signal power, and you need to not fall below the required power level. You should have a defined power budget and stay within the limits of that.

Answer (score 1):

Using duplex LC, OM4 is good for up to 550 m of 1000BASE-SX, 400 m of 10GBASE-SR, or 100 m of 25GBASE-SR.

That nominal reach includes a total insertion loss budget of 3.43 dB for OM4, modeled for four optical connections (transceiver - patch cable - building cable - patch cable - transceiver). Estimating a good insertion loss of .5 dB per connection, six connections are still within the limit. However, depending on the quality of your connections and the total length of fiber, your actual reach may vary.

Often connectors and transceivers somewhat exceed the nominal specifications, but if your double-patched run approaches or even exceeds the values above you'll want to rigorously test the connection. You should test using various transceivers, so you don't run into trouble should a replacement of an exceptionally good transceiver become necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Always depends on connection types and distance. Follow the specs of the cable or jumper. If everything has good connections and is wired correctly, there should never be any issues patching from point to point.

1G circuits and maybe even 10G shouldn't matter as long as your connections are solid.

Long distances with light can be iffy, but as long as the data hits hardware again before it gets sent somewhere there's no real danger on data loss. Just more stuff that can fail and cause a disconnect.

Comment: This answer does not actually meet the specifications or standards. For example, connections and splices should result in no more than a 3 db loss for each, but you can only have so many before exceeding your calculated power budget, and a poor connection or splice can blow the entire power loss budget. It is not a simple matter of an end-to-end connection.

Comment: I've worked with a lot of COs and I've had too much light more times than I've had not enough. Sometimes it's easier to just run copper.